# How to aggregate/group_by against two variables?

Tags: r

Lets say I have a df structured in the following way:

```
  Date          Country     Count
1/21/2020   Mainland China  1
1/21/2020   Mainland China  5
1/21/2020   Mainland China  2
1/21/2020   United States   2
1/21/2020   United States   3
1/23/2020   Mainland China  3
1/23/2020   Mainland China  6
1/23/2020   Mainland China  3
1/23/2020   United States   4
1/23/2020   United States   5
```

But instead I want something like this:

```
   Date         Country     N
1/21/2020   Mainland China  8
1/21/2020   United States   5
1/23/2020   Mainland China  12
1/23/2020   United States   9
```

Where I want the sum of count WITHIN each Date + Country. How would I go about accomplishing this? (the df is actually much larger than the example here).

I have already tried group_by(date, country) and using aggregate(N ~ Date + Country, df, sum) but I keep getting something like this:

```
   Date         Country     N
1/21/2020   Mainland China  8
1/21/2020   United States   5
1/23/2020   Mainland China  20
1/23/2020   United States   14
```

Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: `aggregate(Count~Date+Country, df, sum)` Or using `dplyr`, `df %>% group_by(Date, Country) %>% summarise(Count = sum(Count))`

Comment: Your code looks fine to me - are you sure you aren't just using `N` instead of `Count`?